# Queens on a torus chessboard.

Tags: recreational-mathematics, combinatorial-game-theory

Consider a Torus chessboard  $\mathbb T$ of dimension $8\times8 $.

How much queens it is possible to put on in such a way that no one attacks another? (I assume we use the same rules of standard chess).

Obviously one can decide to use brute force but I 'm looking for a better solution. Thanks.

On $\mathbb T$ two or more queens attack the same number of squares, $28$ if I counted well, and I'm trying to say that $8$ queens attack more than $64- 7$ squares. (I'm assuming that it 's impossible to put eight queens).

Comment: Please share your thoughts and efforts.

Comment: I'd approach by trying to find an upper bound based on the number of squares controlled by each subsequent queen (something like 4 or 5?), and then exhibit a placement that realizes the upper bound.

Comment: Actually, I think it would be 27 - the two diagonals from $(m, n) \in (\mathbb{Z} / 8\mathbb{Z})^2$ intersect at $(m+4, n+4)$.

Comment: It is not hard to verify that it is impossible to put eight queens. It suffices to check the 12 different solutions to the eight queens problem [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle#Solutions).

Comment: @Neal The maximum is either $6$ or $7$, as witnessed by the placement a1, b4, c2, d7, e3, g8.

Comment: In fact the maximum turns out to be $6$, but my proof isn't much prettier than brute force.

Comment: I don't think you can do better than the classical backtracking solution for the 8 queens problem.